# What is the highest-performing free Linux command line converter that will convert HTML + cover to ePub?

Tags: epub

I have been discovering that Calibre's `ebook-convert` runs painfully slow converting HTML + cover image to ePub with a >1M input. Pandoc also seemed slow.

What, if anything, can I do to run things faster? Is there any way I can get (or get instructions to build) a template which could have the HTML and cover dropped in?

The impression I got from Wikipedia is that it's a relatively straightforward format, but I wanted to check in if there's something else already built that I should consider.